# Pulling mysql data into a multidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've checked all kinds of previously answered similar questions and nothing's working.  I have a "Inbox" type application where a person of emailaddress@xyz.com might have 5 messages waiting for them.  They log in and get a screen of those five messages, the sender email, the date sent, and the first 15 chars of the message.

In mysql, I have:  id, emailaddress, senderemail, datesent, fullmessage.

I'm using `SELECT * FROM db WHERE emailaddress='emailaddress@xyz.com'` to pull out, let's say, 5 new messages. `$result` equals the mysql query.  `mysql_num_rows` does a great job of telling me there are 5 rows.  It works fine up to that point.

My problem is that I can't (despite hours of trying) find the right syntax for making this into a multidimensional array so that I can iterate table rows in a for loop and print it all out.  I'm envisioning:

```
<table>
for ($a = 0; $a < $numrows; $a++) {
<tr>
     the php code would go here and would print the associated sender, date, and message in <td> cells.
</tr>
}
</table>
```

Any help would be fantastic.

I'm sure this is not hard but have just not gotten anywhere for most of the afternoon.  Can anyone out there tell me what a simple syntax for doing this would be?

Comment: Please show the PHP code that you have so far. You can't put a `for` loop in HTML, so is this some kind of template file for some PHP framework?

Comment: How, exactly, is this different from the countless questions on retrieving data from MySQL and displaying the results in an HTML table?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Printing Query Results in a Table](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1999815/), [Reading data from a MySQL database into a HTML Table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2595832/), [Create table with PHP and populate from MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3050558/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Information that comes from the database is in an array when you use `mysql_fetch_array()` or `mysql_fetch_assoc()`. So, you can do something like:

```
<table>
<?php
$storage_array = array();
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM db WHERE emailaddress='emailaddress@xyz.com'" or die(mysql_error());

while($data = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
?>
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $data['sender'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $data['date'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $data['message '] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
  $storage_array[] = $data;
}
?>
</table>
```

You will obviously need to join some tables for messages if they are on different tabels or use `LIMIT` to only get 5 rows. You will also need to determine your `ORDER BY`.

You will need to know which loop added your data to `$storage_array` and remember it starts with `$storage_array[0]`.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for except that there's multiple rows that have "emailaddress@xyz.com" and I want to get ALL the rows.  This would just be if there was one row with emailaddress='emailaddress@xyz.com', right?

Comment: Okay, actually, this works great.  :-)  But now I'm wondering how to access that data so I can assign it to variables.  Or maybe the question is whether it's better to put it first into a multidimensional array and then create the table using those variables?  Either way, THANK YOU for the help!  :-)

Comment: This is creating a table by looping through the data. Are you needing to pull two arrays and loop through them? You can access the current row by calling `$data['']` and the `['']` part is the name of the table column.

Comment: How do I access NON-current row data?  I ended up doing exactly what you've got only instead of "echo" I store the data in variables.  Then access by "$array[$row#]['columntitle'].  But it seems like there must be a more elegant or php-did-the-work-for-me way.

Comment: What do you need the non-current row for? You could save it to an array with each pass to have it available. I edited my answer to show it.